# Counting instances of apples and bananas next to each other

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have a apples and b bananas arranged in a line and I generate all possible permutations of that arrangement (# would be ((b+a) choose a) or ((b+a) choose b).

For each arrangement, how do I count the number of times an apple is next to a banana or vice-versa in terms of general a and b. If the arrangement is abba, the number of times would be 2. If the arrangement is bab, again the number of times would be 2

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Your question is not clear. You say "for each arrangement" but then say "in terms of $a$ and $b$". When you say "for each arrangement" you are asking for a number that depends on which sequence of a's and b's you have; it cannot simply depend on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: If $a=1$ and $b=2$, then there are three arrangements: abb with $1$ instance, bab with $2$ instances, and bba with $1$ instance. So whatever you are looking for is more complicated than something which can be worked out only from $a$ and $b$. In _total_ all these arrangements provide $4$ instances, and that _is_ a number which can be worked out from $a$ and $b$. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=a+b$. For $i=2$ to $n$, we say that there is a *transition* at $i$ if the contents of position $i$ are different from the contents of position $i-1$. Choose a permutation "at random." Define the *indicator* random variables $X_i$ by $X_i=1$ if there is a transition at $i$, and $0$ otherwise.

The probability there is an apple at $i-1$ is $\frac{a}{n}$. Given that there is an apple at $i-1$, the probability there is a banana at $i$ is $\frac{b}{n-1}$. So the probability of an apple-banana transition at $i$ is $\frac{ab}{n(n-1)}$. We get the same probability for a banana-apple transition.

The number of $T$ of transitions is $\sum_2^n X_i$. By the linearity of expectation, we have
$$E(T)=E\left(\sum_2^n X_i\right)=\sum_2^n E(X_i).$$
It follows that the expected number of transitions is $\frac{2ab}{n}$.

Multiply by the number $\binom{n}{a}$ of arrangements to get the total number of transitions over all arrangements. We can simplify a little, and get the more symmetric-looking
$$\frac{2(a+b-1)!}{(a-1)!(b-1)!}$$
for the total number of transitions.

**Remark:** There is undoubtedly a simpler way to get the above expression, but the above *mean* proof is the first thing that came to mind. Indicator random variables, and the linearity of expectation can be very useful tools.